# Can intestinal bacterial overgrowth result in hypophosphatemia?

Tags: bacteria, absorption-absorb, irritable-bowel-syndrome, intestine, gut-microbiota-flora

[This article shows](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6278197/) that there is variability in the degree that bacteria bind to phosphate in the gut. Is it possible that intestinal bacterial overgrowth results in hypophosphatemia?

Answer (score 1):

Chronic small intestinal bacterial overgrowth (SIBO) can be associated with decreased calcium and vitamin D absorption, which can result in increased parathormone secretion, which can result in increased excretion of phosphate through the kidneys and thus in hypophosphatemia. In short-term cases, there would be no hypocalcemia, because calcium would be leached from the bones and maintain normal blood levels.

Source: [Small Intestinal Bacterial Overgrowth: A Possible Risk Factor for Metabolic Bone Disease (Nutrition Reviews, 2003)](https://watermark.silverchair.com/nutritionreviews61-0132.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAsMwggK_BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggKwMIICrAIBADCCAqUGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMFJoRHodLZKBMokasAgEQgIICdqgGJPqr1Z-7tiGVSLrYzaov0eTg0qPIqgUPByk-A-IlQA5eiZUHC6lFGwP7rVwoDq1F9Ingo4BKMyMnPXI1vmPZA9w8l9bq8FaMxIxcPL1PioRUMhEVkcE_l7c07sc2q19hZZ4t5Bf9mUTQyOV7MMOVbPtelf2JAVjl5RmHP-v_k1NdK-dNzobHm8QXeUjSDhGVBodnt-ee1Q3MutlO7VtMmOZ-1r1WGiubsnm-1fvK4pLCkNxkHLGxoUdj_hQH48229t2IapFI3AJvC04Z-euML5wADil2AWZ_PMUVIHcB5IFZBaanwH-lYVznUo3wuywqm1aI4z4E0p2MJqsADGaXjJVS1fZUYrOcZuupGVE8dYkdcmttohqVJbM8vwD36FsV9FldKqV5HIvP3PI3XDdJhldpwhGfILOLaWHl0wSDvLBARa6mo39nlMrYYQyeEHp_af-3Y482I7Q7K4EHSN2He4bBOuNWuj_b84EYGC96-2FoWn4Q2y6Y2-2Ua_zScZiufVHBh9fqoFQmEfh7Lfxfj7HkF8KiSVOnJXIQ0tVQHQuZ1KghmSGg1ApYgOc9FCmth9I6jOavXZDDd0HtGfhc0pvnjNIXFH13DZPHujngjGM8FHUghEo4in_gOWD_kASg9VvYuy72B9qgZ9K45SjGKAak5bhOhytYTXwMimGXVrVw8gZMlq4hXa5QrDUrHqqavsnD74dTWUPiS4SP5039cSTPHuXesx9auMv1v_mSyNiWYO1IlL9qLCxFzyLJCLNbxFUCc5vQeGbEwRKALnOrMsfCGqp-2CNVnXLrm931aEQGW5Illc3r2JSa8IkM2BApPpbY5A)

---

SIBO can be diagnosed by a hydrogen breath test. If the test is negative, other malabsorption conditions can be considered, for example, fructose malabsorption, lactose intolerance, celiac disease, Crohn's disease, etc.